# Visual studio 2010 references or component name for Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm doing an application upgrade by changing the provider from  Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0  to  Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in the source code.

According to the picture below the ACEOLEDB.DLL looks installed on the computer but I can't find this reference in my project from the COM tab.

[image]

[image]

Did try the browse tab and navigate to the dll but it produces the  following error message.

[image]

need help to solve this issue

Comment: It is not how it works, you must change [the connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Assembly tab, not the COM tab. Note in the search box in the top right hand corner of the dialog you can find items via typing in, in this case off for office.

If you don't find the reference and you are sure it's installed you need to browse for it. If not installed of course you need to install it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!